# Statistical method

Tags: java, statistics

So in my code, it seems that in the `fillRandomArray` method, instead of getting an array of 100 random numbers, I just get straight zeros and I don't know how to fix it.  It seems to me that the problem has to do with the first for loop, or potentially the declaration of the double array in the public class statistical model.

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.util.*;
import java.util.Arrays;

public class statisticalModel {
    //Initates a place for the normal curve to be placed.
    static double Ho;
    //Real proportion of data statistic.
    static double Ha;
    //Estimated real proportion of data statistic.
    static int Pop;
    //Population size.
    static int Zscore;
    //Z score, or the amount of standard deviations away from the mean.
    //Z score = sqrt(P(1-p)/N)
    static double stdDev;
    //Standard Deviation, follows the 65, 95, 99 model.  65 percent of all scores
    //fall in one standard deviation of the mean.  95 percent of all scores fall
    //within two standard deviations of the mean.  99 percent of all scores fall
    //within three standard deviations of the mean.
    static double mean;
    //The average of all the scores of the array.
    static double variance;
    //The average difference between sets of values within the array.
    static double[] meanScores = new double[100];
    //Array meant to generate a set of random values within the normal curve of
    //the model, following the 65, 95, 99 rule.
    static String desiredValue = "";
    //This is a string set to the user's command.  Tells whether or not the value should
    //be lower than, higher than, or not equal to Ho.
    static Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    //Scanner to take in values listed above.
    static int size = 100;
    //Variable that measures the size of the array.
    static int temporary;
    //Value Holder for For Loops, While Loops, If Statements, etc.
    static double pValue;

    //P Value which represents how far a statistic deviates from the expected mean of a population.
    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        runStatisticalMethod();
    }

    public static void runStatisticalMethod()
    {
        takeInData();
        calculateStats();
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(meanScores));
        explainSolution();
    }

    public static void takeInData()
    {
        System.out.println("Please enter your desired Ho");
        Ho = sc.nextDouble();
        System.out.println("Please enter your desired Ha");
        Ha = sc.nextDouble();
        System.out.println("Please enter your desired population size");
        Pop = sc.nextInt();
        System.out.println("Thanks for entering your data.  Your data will be compiled below");
    }

    //Fills the array meanScores with random integers.
    public static void fillRandomArray()
    {
        for (int z = 0; z < 100; z++) {
            meanScores[z] = (Math.random() * 100) + (stdDev * 3);
        }
        assignStdDev();
        for (int x = 0; x < 99; x++) {
            for (int y = 0; y < 99; y++) {
                if (meanScores[y] >= meanScores[y + 1]) {
                    double valueHolder1 = meanScores[y];
                    double valueHolder2 = meanScores[y + 1];
                    meanScores[y + 1] = valueHolder1;
                    meanScores[y] = valueHolder2;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public static void assignStdDev()
    {
        for (int x = 5; x >= 5 && x <= 95; x++) {
            meanScores[x] -= (stdDev * Math.random());
        }
        for (int x = 31; x >= 31 && x < 66; x++) {
            meanScores[x] -= (stdDev * Math.random());
        }
    }

    //Calculates a set of statistics including standard deviation, z-score, mean,
    //interquartile range, probability, and variance.
    public static void calculateStats()
    {
        //Calculates the Mean of the inputted variables and normal curve.
        int sum = 0;
        for (int a = 0; a < 100; a++) {
            sum += a;
        }
        mean = sum / size;
        //Calculate the Variance of the inputted variables and normal curve.
        for (int b = 0; b < 100; b++) {
            temporary += (b - mean) * (b - mean);
        }
        variance = temporary / size;
        //Calculate the Standard Deviation of the inputted variables and normal curve.
        stdDev = Math.sqrt(variance);
        //Calculate the P-Value and use the p value to determine whether or not the hypothesis is valid.
        pValue = (Ha - Ho) / (stdDev / Math.sqrt(Pop));
    }

    //This method explains the numbers generated in terms of statistics and analyzes
    //if the hypothesis is probably.  If not, a possible solution is proposed with
    //regards to what should be changed.  Also explains the curve of the graph.
    public static void explainSolution()
    {
        if (Math.abs(pValue) < .05) {
            System.out.println(
                "Based on the information you have given me, the hypothesis test seems to show information that your Ha is possibly correct, thus failing to reject your hypothesis");
        } else if (Math.abs(pValue) > .05) {
            System.out.println(
                "Based on the information you have given me, the hypothesis test seems to lack information to show that your Ha is possibly correct, thus rejecting your hypothesis");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: but where are you calling fillRandomArray ??

Comment: @ΦXocę웃Пepeúpaツ is right i have tested also you dont call assignStdDev too, update your runStatisticalMethod

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  It looks like you need to learn to use a debugger.  Please help yourself to some [complementary debugging techniques](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/).  If you still have issues afterwards, please feel free to come back with more details.